# How can i scrape information from web page?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to programming and need some help with my web-crawler.

At the moment, I have my code opening up every web-page in the list. However, I wish to extract information from each one it loads. This is what I have.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
links_code = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="in-match"]')
first_two = links_code[0:2]
first_two_links = []

for i in first_two:
    link = i.get_attribute("href")
    first_two_links.append(link)


for i in first_two_links:
    driver.get(i)
```

This loops through the first two pages but scrapes no info. So I tried adding to the for-loop as follows

```
odds = []
for i in first_two_links:
    driver.get(i)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="table-main__detail- 
    odds--hasarchive"]')
    odds.append(odd)
```

However. This runs into an error. 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

First, after you start the driver you need to go to a website...

Second, in the second for loop, you are trying to append the wrong object... use `i` not `odd` or make `odd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="table-main__detail-odds--hasarchive"]')`

***If you can provide the URL or the HTML we can help more!***

Try this (I have used Google as an example you will need to change the code...):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
links_code = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a')
first_two = links_code[0:2]
first_two_links = []

for i in first_two:
    link = i.get_attribute("href")
    first_two_links.append(link)

    print(link)


odds = []
for i in first_two_links:
    driver.get(i)
    odd = driver.page_source
    print(odd)
    # driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="table-main__detail- odds--hasarchive"]')
    odds.append(odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually appending anything! you need to assign a variable to

> driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="table-main__detail- 
>       odds--hasarchive"]')

then append it to the list!

```
from selenium import webdriver;
import csv;
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
links_code : list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="in-match"]');
first_two : list = links_code[0:2];
first_two_links : list = [];

i : int;
for i in first_two:
    link = i.get_attribute("href");
    first_two_links.append(link);


for i in first_two_links:
    driver.get(i);


odds : list = [];
i :int;
for i in first_two_links:
    driver.get(i);
    o = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="table-main__detail- odds--hasarchive"]');
    odds.append(o);
```

Comment: Hi, you are correct yet what have you added in your answer that was not in my own? Also, the question is in python... you have `;` all over and typing is supported only from Python 3.7

Comment: I used python 3.6.5, **;** is supported in every Python version!

Comment: It is not pythonic... python is indent- sensitive... Also, what have you added on my answer?

Comment: I didn't even look into your answer tbh and your answer is **WRONG**!

Comment: And this is the most "Pythonic" you can get because it runs both on Idle and python terminal virtual machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189127/discussion-between-moshe-slavin-and-andrej-hatzi).